# Boot to USB from Shell?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, grub-efi, recovery-mode

I can't boot into the OS (I'm getting Oh no! Something went wrong.). I can boot into grub (and edit grub to open shell), or boot into recovery and open shell from there. Normally, I would just boot to USB and refresh/reinstall the system, but I can't. It's a 2010 MacBook Pro and it doesn't matter how many times I reset PRAM (option+command+P+R keys), it won't show the USB (I've done this several times before just recently when USB didn't show, and it always worked). I've reset PRAM like ten times now, and I still can't get it to work. So I'm looking for an alternate way to boot into the USB drive with Ubuntu Live.

Verified download, checksum results:

```
ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```

Media written with Balena Etcher on Windows. Formatted drive, wrote with Balena Etcher again, tried again, same result on Macbook. Have another laptop with Ubuntu (same version) and used Startup Disk Creator to flash USB again with iso, and finally I could get the Macbook to detect the USB drive after another PRAM reset. It worked fine with Windows for previous installs on the Macbook; don't know why rewriting with Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu would make the difference.

However, I'm still looking for the command to boot from USB from shell for Macbook running Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop, for future reference anyway.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by 'shell' in "boot from USB from shell"? 2. If you don't want a graphical desktop environment, you can put an 'installed Ubuntu Server system' into the USB drive according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692).

Comment: I mean from command line. Like, when you boot into recovery and then open up command line, but it's outside of the OS (GUI not running; like, maybe the GUI won't run, or there's some kind of problem).